# how to remove space in number data type format in salesforce?

Tags: custom-field, fields

below is the screen shot which is highlighting the number field format , so i need to remove the space EX :2342355435 , not like this format 2 342 355 435

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your field type to text. Number fields are automatically displayed in the user's locale. These type of fields are not suitable for unformatted numeric data.

Comment: Hi, it's has to support only digits not other characters

Comment: @Prasanth you can enforce that by a validation rule. If you don't want the thousands separator, it needs to be text.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here

First create a new formula field and formula `TEXT` and you will get unformatted value.

Second use trigger and remove space using string function `deleteWhitespace()` and it will remove all space.

Comment: The second option won't work... This is a number field, so it's formatted per the user's locale.

Comment: Thank you Tushar Sharma, i will try second option, if work's then will mark it other's wise i will ask for help.

Comment: @sfdcfox I think second option will work  might need some work. Because SF format the text on UI (maybe using JavaScript) and in trigger we can easily remove the formatting. I have tried this on Phone number and it works well.

Comment: Thank you Tushar Sharma, i am thinking to change data type text and writing validation rule to enter only digits in field.